# What's the proper way to structure this set of try catch blocks with respect to variable initializations?

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm practicing java by trying my hand at a simple calculator challenge from an online course. The purpose is to take numeric inputs plus the desired operation (+, -, %, *), while also handling non numeric inputs and unlisted operators. Below is my attempt:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double d1;
        double d2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            d1 = getInput(sc);
            d2 = getInput(sc);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Non numeric value entered.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(calculate(sc, d1, d2));
        } catch(OperationNotSupportedException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

 private static double calculate(Scanner scanner, double d1, double d2) throws OperationNotSupportedException {
        System.out.print("Enter the desired operation: ");
        String op = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(op);

        switch (op) {
            case "-":
                return d1 - d2;
            case "+":
                return d1 + d2;
            case "*":
                return d1 * d2;
            case "/":
                return d1 / d2;
            default:
                throw new OperationNotSupportedException("The operation not one of (+ - % *)");
        }
    }

    private static double getInput(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.printf("Enter a numeric value: ");
        return sc.nextDouble();
    }
```

So the issue is that compiler sees a problem in the second `try-catch` block. Namely `d1` and `d2` may not have been initialized. I can see why that would be true in the case that an error is thrown in the first `try-catch`. I figured that putting `System.exit()` might satisfy the compiler, but it didn't.

How could I restructure my code to achieve the desired results?

Comment: In this particular instance I'd move what's in the second `try` into the first `try` and catch both exceptions there. Once either of them is caught there's no doubt one was thrown by `getInput` and the other one from `calculate`

Comment: exit() is just a method call. The compiler does not know that a particular  method will not return.   Me, I'd just initialize d1 and d2 (0 will do).  But I concur with @FedericoklezCulloca; as written, there seems to be no need for two try-blocks.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Okay, that makes good sense!

Comment: @something That's fair. I guess I thought it might not be transparent to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first initialization of d1 and d2 are within a try block, there is a possibility that those variables might not get initialized by the end of the first try block (in case of an exception). In such a case, you cannot use those variables to call `calculate` in the second try block, as those would still not be initialized.

just initialize as:

```java
double d1 = 0d;
double d2 = 0d;
```

Comment: Thank you. I decided to combine the two try-catch blocks as was suggested in the comments. However, I'm going to accept your answer as it would clearly solve my problem.

Comment: @rocksNwaves Yes you could combine those try block and use multiple catch block to handle the specific exception since your catch statements seems to be different for each exception. Otherwise you could have used a single catch like :`catch(InputMismatchException | OperationNotSupportedException e)`